# Ruby on Rails - Refresh data when button pressed

Tags: jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a website which contains photos and videos and 3 buttons. One show only photos, one only videos and the last one show photos & videos. I have two different tables in the database (photos, videos) which contains only the name of the file. Their is no relationship between them.
Here is a example of my AJAX used to only show videos :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-videos').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'/galerie',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'type' : "videos", }
    });
    });
});
```

Here is my galerie controller :

```
  def index
     case params[:type]
     when "videos"  
        @medias = Video.order('created_at DESC')
     when "images" 
        @medias = Picture.order('created_at DESC')
     else 
        @medias = (Video.order('created_at DESC') + Picture.order('created_at DESC')).sort_by { |model| model.created_at }.in_groups_of(3)
     end
  end
```

My AJAX is calling the controller but it doesn't update the view.
Is their a (better) way to do this ? 
 I'm also wondering if its possible to do this line using only sql :

```
@medias = (Video.order('created_at DESC') + Picture.order('created_at DESC')).sort_by { |model| model.created_at }.in_groups_of(3)
```

Comment: Instead of ajax in js file I will say call with remote and handle it via `index.js.erb`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

1. send a remote request through your button and handle data update on index.js.erb file (in views folder). You can refer to [this](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy) link.
2. Use ajax in js file in your asset. Once the ajax request is successful you need to replace your old data with your requested new data.

   ```
   $('#btn-videos').on 'click', ->
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax
        type:'GET',
        url:'/galerie',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'type' : "videos", }
        success: (data) ->
          console.log(data)
   ```